# Appending data with FatFS in a uSD

Tags: microcontroller, sd-card, fatfs

I am using a SAMG55 and the FatFS library included in the ASF, everything seems to work properly, but when I try to append data to a file periodically it only works the first time. I mean, if my file has a size of 100, the first time the microcontroller open the file it says that the size is 100, but then I write a line and close the file. Next time I open it without rebooting the microcontroller it says that the size is always 4, the line is longer that 4 bytes.

This is the code I am using:

```
f_open(&file_object, (char const *)test_file_name, FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_WRITE );
f_lseek(&file_object, file_object.fsize);
f_printf(&file_object, " Some data line \r\n");
f_close(&file_object);
```

Do you have any idea about what is happening?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is not writing into the file, if I remove the f_printf and only open and close the file it remains happening. File size 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

In `f_open()`, use the flag `FA_OPEN_APPEND` instead of `FA_OPEN_ALWAYS`. Then you don’t have to use `f_lseek()`. So try this:

```
f_open(&file_object, (char const *)test_file_name, FA_OPEN_APPEND | FA_WRITE );
f_printf(&file_object, " Some data line \r\n");
f_close(&file_object);
```